# Webpack build - separate html, css and js output paths

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm writing a React app that integrates with an existing Flask project. If I build the app, take the index.html and move it into Flask's templates, take the js and css folders from the build and move them to Flask's static folder, everything works fine.

What I'd like to do now is ensure that a one step build is possible, which would mean building the React app in such a way that index.html is output directly into Flask's templates and statics are output directly into Flask's statics. I don't know if this is at all possible, though.

Is it possible to configure Webpack to use separate output paths for HTML, js and css when making a build? (Extra info, I'm using an ejected create-react-app to be able to go through Webpack config.)

If it's not possible, is there a different way I could ensure a one step build (e.g. build to default, then move to separate folders automatically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple to configure where the output should go. First and foremost, you need to set `output.path` to your flask directory. For instance if you kept the structure of Create React App (CRA) after ejecting and the flask directory is a sibling directory to your app, the `output` would look like this:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../flask'),
  filename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js',
  chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
  publicPath: publicPath
}
```

Now you need to change where the `index.html` goes, and as CRA uses `html-webpack-plugin` you can set the `filename` option to `template/index.html`, similarly to `output.filename`:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  filename: 'template/index.html',
  template: paths.appHtml,
  minify: {
    // Minify options
  }
}),
```

As CRA already configured the CSS outputs to be in `static/css` you don't need to change anything for it.

With the default CRA app the content of the flask directory is a follows:

```
flask
├─ asset-manifest.json
├─ static
│  ├─ css
│  │  ├─ main.9a0fe4f1.css
│  │  └─ main.9a0fe4f1.css.map
│  ├─ js
│  │  ├─ main.1ca7fdbb.js
│  │  └─ main.1ca7fdbb.js.map
│  └─ media
│     └─ logo.5d5d9eef.svg
└─ template
  └─ index.html
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!